# group by inside group by throws linq error

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I am having below linq query

```
 var asq = from der in result
                      group der by der.RX_ID into grouped
                      where grouped.Count() > 1
                      select new
                      {
                          RxID = grouped.Key,
                          Records = from ser in grouped
                                    group ser by ser.claim_id into g2
                                    where g2.Count()> 1 
                                    select new { ClaimId = g2.Key, RecordsClaim = g2.ToList() }
                      };
```

first of all grouping by `Rx_ID` and then grouping it by `claim_id` in another set.
but it throws  the

> `type <anonymous type> <claimid ,records claim> exists in both dll`.

how can i use anonymous types in multiple group by statement.

Comment: What is input and what is expected output?

Comment: @MaciejLos that is the very complex logic to write out put here. i need to group  by one id and then based upon the grouping need to perform another group by with different id

Comment: Check [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2f35003-9654-42af-ab46-be100f68cc3f/the-type-fanonymoustypee-exists-in-both-and-entityframeworkdll?forum=adodotnetentityframework)